# why does const return prevent: (a1 = a2) = a3?

Tags: c++, constants, assignment-operator, chaining

I do not understand why adding `const` to the return type prevents `(a1 = a2) = a3`, as the comment at line 2 says.
Can someone explain it for me?

```
// overloaded assignment operator;
// const return prevents: (a1 = a2) = a3
const Array& Array::operator=(const Array& right) {
    if (&right != this) { // avoid self-assignment
       // for Arrays of different sizes, deallocate original
       // left-side Array, then allocate new left-side Array
        if (size != right.size) {
            delete[] ptr; // release space
            size = right.size; // resize this object
            ptr = new int[size]; // create space for Array copy
        }

        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i) {
            ptr[i] = right.ptr[i]; // copy array into object
        }
    }

    return *this; // enables x = y = z, for example
}
```

Comment: The return type is `const Array&`. The `const` makes it so you can't chain assignments (how can you assign to something that is `const`?).

Comment: Return a lvalue reference `Array&` without const

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"?

Answer (score 2):

When evaluating the expression:

```
a1 = a2 = a3
```

the grouping is from right to left, so the expression becomes:

```
a1 = (a2 = a3)
//   ^^^^^^^^^ const, but evaluated first, so ok.
```

This is fine, since the parenthesized expression yields a `const` value which can be used as the argument to `operator=`.

However in the expression:

```
  (a1 = a2) = a3
//^^^^^^^^^ const, but evaluated first, so assigning to the result is not ok.
```

the parenthesized expression again yields a `const` value, but now you are trying to assign to a `const` value, which is impossible.

Comment: Well, assigning to a const value would technically be possible in case the assignment operator was const qualified. But that would be just silly :)

Comment: Haha, true, syntactically valid, but meaningless. Or actively confusing.